# Accessing Basic Auth credentials

Tags: go, basic-authentication, go-alice

I'm working on an API using GoLang. All calls to this API will contain a `public_key` (username) and some will also contain a `private_key` (password) in the Authorization header.

I'm trying to figure out how to access the Auth header details so that I can check the credentials against a database.

I'm using Julien Schmidt's router and Alice to chain middleware. My setup so far is:

```
func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("conn-string")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    c := appContext{session.DB("db-name")}
    commonHandlers := alice.New(context.ClearHandler)
    router := NewRouter()
    router.Get("/", commonHandlers.Append(basicAuthHandler).ThenFunc(c.mainHandler))

    http.ListenAndServe(":5000", router)
}
```

but I'm not sure how to continue with the `basicAuthHandler` function below. If the `public_key` is present I need to check that it's valid. The same for the `private_key` if that's included.

```
func basicAuthHandler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    }

    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}
```

Comment: It's best not to misuse terms like [public/private key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key) that have very specific meanings.

Comment: Ok, `app_id` and `secret`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running the function [`BasicAuth`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.BasicAuth) on the request:

```
user, password, ok := r.BasicAuth()
if !ok {
  // could not get basic authentication credentials
}
```